# How to test endpoints protected by csrf in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, request, csrf

I have implemented csrf (cross-site request forgery) protection in an express like so:

```
...
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
...
```

This works great. Angularjs utilized the csrf token in all requests made through the $http service. The requests that I make through my angular app work great.

My problem is testing these api endpoints. I'm using mocha to run my automated tests and the request module to test my api endpoints. When I make a request to an endpoint that utilizes csrf (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) using the request module, it fails, even though it correctly utilizes cookies and such.

Has anybody else come up with a solution to this? Does anyone need more information?

Example of test:

```
function testLogin(done) {
  request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + '/api/login',
    json: {
      email: 'myemail@email.com',
      password: 'mypassword'
    } 
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    // do stuff to validate returned data
    // the server spits back a 'FORBIDDEN' string,
    // which obviously will not pass my validation
    // criteria
    done();
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you put a sample of the tests you have tried to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is that you need to wrap your POST test inside a GET and parse the necessary CSRF token from the cookie. First, this assumes you create an Angular-compatible CSRF cookie like this:

```
.use(express.csrf())
.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.session._csrf);
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.session._csrf;
  next();
})
```

Then, your test could look like this:

```
describe('Authenticated Jade tests', function () {
  this.timeout(5000);

  before(function (done) {
    [Set up an authenticated user here]
  });

  var validPaths = ['/help', '/products'];

  async.each(validPaths, function (path, callback) {
    it('should confirm that ' + path + ' serves HTML and is only available when logged in', function (done) {
      request.get('https://127.0.0.1:' + process.env.PORT + path, function (err, res, body) {
        expect(res.statusCode).to.be(302);
        expect(res.headers.location).to.be('/login');
        expect(body).to.be('Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to /login');

        var csrftoken = unescape(/XSRF-TOKEN=(.*?);/.exec(res.headers['set-cookie'])[1]);
        var authAttributes = { _csrf: csrftoken, email: userAttributes.email, password: 'password' };

        request.post('https://127.0.0.1:' + process.env.PORT + '/login', { body: authAttributes, json: true }, function (err, res) {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.be(303);

          request.get('https://127.0.0.1:' + process.env.PORT + path, function (err, res, body) {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.be(200);
            expect(body.toString().substr(-14)).to.be('</body></html>');

            request.get('https://127.0.0.1:' + process.env.PORT + '/bye', function () {
              done();
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });

    callback();
  });
});
```

The idea is to actually login and use post the CSRF token you're getting from the cookie. Note that you need the following at the top of the mocha test file:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true, followRedirect: false});
```

Comment: This looks like it'll be the one that does it. I was hoping I wouldn't have to nest requests like that, so I may just disable csrf when running tests.

Comment: It's admittedly a bit of a pain, but you can't realistically do an end-to-end test if you leave out CSRF.

Comment: That's true... I've also thought about using a different testing framework like phantomjs where I can test more of the interaction with the the app rather than just the endpoints, but I suppose it would be good to do both. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's highly working well with node.js! Thanks for sharing your idea about the usage of cookies!

Comment: If the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is not available and you prefer not to add it in your server, you can obtain the csrf token from the login page's html form with `res.text.match(/name=_csrf value=([^>]*)>/)[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

what i do is expose a csrf token only in non-production:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  app.use('/csrf', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({
      csrf: req.csrfToken()
    })
  })
}
```

then have it be the first test and save it as a global. you'll have to use an agent in your tests so you consistently use the same session.

Comment: How would I then use the csrf token in my request above? If I add

    jar: true

to the request object, it uses cookies and I can see the token and cookie being used, but for some reason it doesn't accept it. So how can I use the token in the request to make it accept it?

Comment: you have to submit it. ie `x-csrf-token: csrf` or add it to the request body. yes, this is annoying, but this is exactly what users must do. make sure the session doesn't change on every request.

Comment: I've been logging out the request and response objects on the testing side and the server side and the token is the same in sequential requests. It's there just as it is when I'm just using the front end of the site hitting those same endpoints. The cookie is there and it's added to the request body on every request after the first one.

Comment: This "annoyance" is good, because this is a test and that makes sure, that the form is in deed needing the csrf to validate and is not ignoring it.

What I don't like in this approach is that you have to make a request beforehand. But I can't figure out a good way to get the (or stub) the token without starting a session.

Answer (score 1):

[@dankohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935918/dankohn)'s excellent answer has been most helpful. Things have changed a bit since then, regarding both supertest and the [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) module. Therefore, in addition to that answer, I have found that the following needs to be passed to the POST:

```
  it('should ...', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/...')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        var csrfToken = unescape(/XSRF-TOKEN=(.*?);/.exec(res.headers['set-cookie'])[1]);
        assert(csrfToken);
        request(app)
          .post('/...')
          .set({cookie: res.headers['set-cookie']})
          .send({
            _csrf: csrfToken,
            ...
          })
          .expect(200)
          .end(done);
      });
  });
```