# Kraken.js CSRF Handling

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

i have a problem with krakenjs, i'm a node/express newbie.

krakenjs is set to default csrf protection (i know how to disable, but i dont want to), but i dont know how to handle csrf and avoiding 403 error.

in ejs file i got this line.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_crsf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

it generates proper csrf, there is no problem in there.

and here is my route

```
server.post('/isengard/fact/new', function(req,res){
    var new_fact = Fact({
        title : req.body.fact_title,
        description : req.body.fact_description,
        source : req.body.fact_source
    });
    new_fact.save(function(err){
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        var model = {status:true};
        res.render('isengard/create',model);
    });
});
```

but when i send form (POST), i'm getting this error.

```
403 Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
at /Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:48:24
at csrf (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:112:13)
at /Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:60:21
at xframe (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:131:9)
at /Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:60:21
at p3p (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:144:9)
at /Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:60:21
at Object.appsec (/Users/onur/Documents/node/sage/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/lusca/index.js:65:9)
```

can anyone explain me how to handle csrf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your problem is that you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_crsf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

instead of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

Note the typo in the `name` attribute.

Comment: Jean-Charles adds good, useful commentary, but this is the correct answer for the original post.

Comment: Where may I read about it? There is no info about how to config it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that you need to wrap your POST test inside a GET and parse the necessary CSRF token from the cookie.

Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776974/1935918

Answer (score 1):

csrf in kraken is pretty much entirely handled by the csrf connect middleware (with the one addition being exposing the token to your views as `_csrf`).

A little more information would go a long way (req/res headers at the least but [an HAR](http://help.tenderapp.com/kb/troubleshooting-single-sign-on/generating-an-har-file) would be awesome) but I can see a few ways this might happen:

1. The csrf *secret* (not token, mind you) is being regenerated or removed some time between the initial `GET` and the `POST`. The only way this is possible is if the value stored as `_csrfSecret` in the session is changed or deleted between requests. Make sure your session is working properly.
2. One of the security headers is giving you grief. Try turning them off **temporarily** with something like the following in your `middleware-development.json`:

   ```
   {
     "middleware": {
       "appsec": {
         "csp": false,
         "xframe": false,
         "p3p": false
       }
     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: In the version this answer was referring to, config was set in `config/middleware.json`. Security is handled by [lusca](https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca). In current kraken (v1.0.x), config is set in [`config/config.json`](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/blob/4ae1cc4d88d7be6ff4f81a25ed718ea8df21fa1e/config/config.json#L122-L136).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need csrf protection, put this in your config.json to disable it altogether.
Then your app runs as it otherwise would.

```
"middleware": {        
      "appsec": {
        "priority": 110,
        "module": {
            "name": "lusca",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "csrf": false,
                    "xframe": "SAMEORIGIN",
                    "p3p": false,
                    "csp": false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```